# WebLogic "MDB application is NOT connected to messaging system"

Tags: jakarta-ee, weblogic, portal

We have a J2EE/portal application running on WebLogic Portal 10.2.  We have recently introduced an asynchronous EJB call, but after putting it into production, we're getting an error message that says

> MDB application *XXX* is NOT connected to messaging system

Is this a coding issue, something that can be tweaked with a runtime parameter, or something that we can ignore?  (Or a fourth option, that I haven't thought of?)

Answer (score 1):

This can also come from a startup problem with the messaging subsystem.  This is usually caused by a persistent store issue.  If you use the admin console to look at Services->Messaging->JMS Servers you can see the status of your JMS servers.  If they are not 'OK' then something is wrong and needs troubleshooting...

Answer (score 0):

This error usually occurs when your MDB is unable to lookup the foreign destination. If you're using a foreign messaging provider, the client jars may be missing from the classpath.

Alternatively, there could be an issue with the JNDI lookup itself. You can validate this by viewing the JNDI tree and ensuring the object you're looking up is bound.